# ¿Como adaptar un codigo de docker run a docker compose exitosamente?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Necesito ayuda con una adaptacion de docker run a docker compose, cuando ejecuto el docker run funciona correctamente pero al pasarlo a docker compose este ya no funciona a pesar de tener los elementos mas importantes para su ejecución.
Docker run:

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet 10.0.0.0/24 --gateway 10.0.0.1 -o parent=eth0 mv_eth0

docker run -d \
--hostname phone.3cx.com.mx \
--memory {MEMORY} \
--memory-swap {SWAP MEMORY} \
--ip 10.0.0.19 \
--network mv_eth0 \
--restart unless-stopped \
-v 3cx/backup:/mnt/backup \
-v 3cx/recordings:/mnt/recordings \
-v 3cx/log:/var/log \
-v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
--security-opt apparmor=unconfined \
--cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
--cap-add NET_ADMIN \
--name 3cx \
ferdytao/3cx:latest
```

Docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  3cx:
    image: ferdytao/3cx
    container_name: 3cx
    hostname: phone.3cx.com.mx
    networks:
      mv_eth0:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.19
    volumes:
      - 3cx/backup:/mnt/backup
      - 3cx/recordings:/mnt/recordings
      - 3cx/log:/var/log
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    security_opt:
      - apparmor=unconfined
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  mv_eth0:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth0
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "10.0.0.0/24"
          gateway: "10.0.0.1"
```

agradezco anticipadamente, su apoyo.

Comment: Bienvenido @Lifrack. ¿Cuál es el error que te muestra por pantalla? Aprovecho para recomendarte [que visites la página de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funciona StackOverflow en español.

Answer (score 1):

He copiado tu archivo `docker-compose.yml` y lo he ejecutado en mi entorno. El error que me muestra es:

```
service "3cx" refers to undefined volume 3cx/backup: invalid compose project
```

Lo que te está diciendo es que estás usando un volumen que no existe.

**¿Por qué te dice que no existe?**

Cuando se ejecutan los volúmenes en `docker run` se entiende que cuando se usa una ruta del equipo real tipo `3cx/backup` es una ruta relativa desde donde se está ejecutando el comando. Esto en docker-compose no es así, lo que entiende con eso es que tiene que buscar un volumen con ese nombre, no una ruta.

Como lo que tú estás buscando es una ruta relativa, debes cambiar la sección de volúmenes por esto:

```
    volumes:
      - ./3cx/backup:/mnt/backup
      - ./3cx/recordings:/mnt/recordings
      - ./3cx/log:/var/log
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
```

Te pongo todo tu archivo con los cambios:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  3cx:
    image: ferdytao/3cx
    container_name: 3cx
    hostname: phone.3cx.com.mx
    networks:
      mv_eth0:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.19
    volumes:
      - ./3cx/backup:/mnt/backup
      - ./3cx/recordings:/mnt/recordings
      - ./3cx/log:/var/log
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    security_opt:
      - apparmor=unconfined
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  mv_eth0:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth0
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "10.0.0.0/24"
          gateway: "10.0.0.1"
```

Te dejo el enlace a la [referencia a volúmenes en docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) por si quieres conocerlo más en profundidad.

Espero te ayude para poder continuar